# How to slow down a rotation animation with CSS?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a spinning keyframe to spin this world image:

```
@keyframes App-world-spin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

which is called by this:

```
.App-world {
    animation: App-world-spin infinite 20s linear;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Which produces this:

[image: A little choppy, but shows the approximate speed of the rotation]

I want to slow it down so as to produce a more realistic speed at which the world turns.

Comment: Isn't  "20s" from "App-world-spin infinite 20s linear;" the speed? You can change it to 100s

Comment: This has nothing to do with React.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change 20s to 200s(econds), for example:

```
animation: App-world-spin infinite 200s linear;
```

The `200s` tells the browser to animate the element for 200 seconds.  So it will take 200 seconds for it to complete a full rotation.  Of course the Earth takes longer so adjust for your purpose :)